# How to get _id after insertion to mongoDb collection using mongoDb java asynchronous driver

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, save, driver

How to get _id after insertion to mongoDb collection using mongoDb java asynchronous driver

```
package test;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoClientConfiguration;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoCollection;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoDatabase;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.Document;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.BuilderFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.DocumentBuilder;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.Aggregate;
import com.xxxx.dto.FeedMongoDTO;

/**
* @author abhi
* 
*/
public class MongoTestService {

public static transient Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FeedMongoOperations.class);

private MongoClient mongo;
private MongoDatabase db;
private MongoCollection collection;

public boolean openDbConnection() {
    try {
        MongoClientConfiguration config = new MongoClientConfiguration();
        config.addServer("localhost:27017");
        config.setMaxConnectionCount(10);

        mongo = MongoFactory.createClient(config);

        db = mongo.getDatabase("feedDatabase");

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean closeDbConnection() {
    try {
        mongo.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public String save(FeedMongoDTO feed, String collectionName) {
    try {

        collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
        DocumentBuilder b = BuilderFactory.start();
        Document d1 = b.add("url", feed.getUrl()).addLong("mongoTimeStamp", feed.getMongoTimestamp())
                .add("feedJsonArray", feed.getFeedJsonArray()).build();

        collection.insert(d1);

        return d1.get("id").toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public FeedMongoDTO getFeed(String mongoId, String collectionName) {

    FeedMongoDTO feedMongoDTO = null;

    try {
        return feedMongoDTO;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Where `FeedMongoDTO` has the structure as given below

```
public class FeedMongoDTO {

    private String id;
    private String url;
    private Long mongoTimeStamp;
    private JSONArray feedJsonArray;

    //  Getters 
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public Long getMongoTimestamp() {
        return mongoTimeStamp;
    }

    public JSONArray getFeedJsonArray() {
        return feedJsonArray;
    }


    //  Setters 
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setMongoTimestamp(Long mongoTimestamp) {
        this.mongoTimeStamp = mongoTimestamp;
    }

    public void setFeedJsonArray(JSONArray feedJsonArray) {
        this.feedJsonArray = feedJsonArray;
    }

}
```

I need to get the value of _id but here `d1.get("id").toString()` is causing `NullPointerException`

And one more thing I am confused whether I am doing the Save() method correctly. Using usual mongodb driver it was pretty much easier.

```
public String save(FeedMongoDTO feed, String collectionName) {
    try {
        mongoTemplate.save(feed, collectionName);
        return feed.getId();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

thanks in advance

Abhilash :)

Comment: try `collection.insert(d1, Durability.ACK);`

Comment: hi orid, thanks for the reply

but when I do as you said I am getting an error

`The method insert(Durability, DocumentAssignable...) in the type MongoCollection is not applicable for the arguments (Document, Durability). change to insertAsync()` 

and when I do as there said I am getting : `The method insertAsync(Durability, DocumentAssignable...) in the type MongoCollection is not applicable for the arguments (Document, Durability) change to insert()`

Comment: My mistake, please flip the order `collection.insert(Durability.ACK, d1);`

Comment: thanks orid, it worked :) but `System.out.println(d1.get("_id").getValueAsString());` gives the result `ObjectId('5150c3da57199014e86bedc6')`

Comment: @abhips: As you discovered the driver will slip a '_id' field with an ObjectId into the document when you do the insert one if there is not already a field with that name.

Comment: hi @RobMoore, are you saying that by changing `id` to `_id` will set the value to something like `5150c3da57199014e86bedc6` instead of `ObjectId('5150c3da57199014e86bedc6')`. I tried doing that but I got the same result, i.e, `ObjectId('5150c3da57199014e86bedc6')`.

Comment: hi @RobMoore, I have simple question, when the 10gen mongoDb driver used the _id property will be set as `_id=5150c3da57199014e86bedc6` but java asynch driver it is set as `_id=ObjectId('5150c3da57199014e86bedc6')`. And what I needed is to get the `5150c3da57199014e86bedc6` part and how can I get it using java-async-driver ?

Comment: The _id is a element of Type ObjectIdElement.  The value of that element is an ObjectId and you are calling toString on it giving the ObjectId('5150c3da57199014e86bedc6').  If you instead call the toHexString() you will get the  5150c3da57199014e86bedc6 part.  Something like: d1.get(ObjectIdElement.class,"_id").toHexString();

Answer (score 4):

If this is something you need to do often, why not just set the _id yourself. You can easily construct a new [ObjectId](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/apidocs/index.html) by using the 0-arg constructor, and just add it to your document before inserting it.

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
documentBuilder.add("_id", id);
collection.insert(documentBuilder);
```

Seems silly to run a separate query just to retrieve the id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the asynchronous java driver provides ways of making synchronous queries, such as with the normal [findOne](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/apidocs/index.html?com/allanbank/mongodb/MongoCollection.html) call.  Does this make sense for your needs?

Comment: hi shelman ,

actually is there any simple strait forward way to get the _id after insertion as given in the last code example in question, where id is obtained without making any new method call as `findOne`.

thanks :)

Comment: Did you try orid's answer?  It seems to me that you have to use a synchronous version of the insert call, since the asynchronous one cannot return you a value in the way that you want.

Comment: hi shelman , I think it is a synchronous method since there is an insertAsync() method with the same method signature.

Comment: Actually, this is the one place in the driver where a Document is not immutable.  There is special handling for the '_id' field to both make detecting a document without one fast and to ensure that even in the asynchronous case the caller gets access to the injected ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself when creating a new Name in my directory with my Asynchronous Node App. I wanted to take the user to the newly created Name via it's ID without throwing the user back to the directory list. allTwentyQuestions got this kind of right, though not quite right for Node, and led me on this path:

```
addName: function(nameDB, newName, callback){
  nameID = new require('mongodb').ObjectID();
  nameDB.collection('nameList').insert({"_id" : nameID, 'Name' : newName, 'type' : '', 'active' : 'no', 'modifiedDate' : ''}, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        // success
        callback(null, nameID);
    } else {
        // error
        callback('error', err);
    }
  });
}
```

I would then call the function from my app:

```
mongo.addName(nameDB, newName, function(err, result) {
  if (!err){
    // success
    // direct the user to the proper page with this new ObjectID found in the var 'result'
  } else {
    // error
    console.log('There was an error adding the name: '+ result);
  }
});
```